# First time with OOP in php

Tags: php, mysql, oop

It's my first time using some OOP in PHP.

I have made this simple login system, but for some reason it doesn't seems to be working.

Whenever I enter some details on the page **admin_login.php** it again redirects me to admin_login.php without saying anything.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

**class.admin.php**

```
<?php
include 'inc/inc.functions.php';
include '..dbconnector.php';

class admin
{
    public function logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['adminLogged'])==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } //function

    public function login_correct($username,$password)
    {
        global $conn;
        try
        {
            $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from admins where username = ? and password = ?");
            $statement->execute(
                array(
                    $username,
                    $password));
            $row=$statement->rowCount();
            if($rows > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }//funcion
}

?>
```

**admin_login.php**

```
<?php

{
    ?>
    <table>
    <form  method="post" action="admin_process.php?process=login">
    <tr>
        <td>Username : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password : </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**admin_process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'class/class.admin.php';
include 'dbconnector.php';
$admin = new admin();

if(isset($_REQUEST['process']))
    {
        switch($_REQUEST['process'])
        {
            case 'login':
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            if($admin->login_correct($username, $password))
            {   
                header('refresh:2;URL=admin_home.php');
                $_SESSION['adminLogged']=1;
                $_SESSION['adminUsername']=$username;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Wrong username or password";
            }
            break;
            default:
            header('Location:admin_home.php');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location:admin_home.php');
    }

?>
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What do you have in your `admin_home.php` ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `$_REQUEST['process']` to `$_REQUEST['submit']` and then try.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be helpful.

Comment: Because your submit button name is "submit" not "process"